# Vagrant keeps trying to use use AWS plugin. How to stop?

Tags: vagrant

I'm just trying to `vagrant up` a standard Ubuntu image for the first time. My company has set up Vagrant on my laptop already and installed some plugins for AWS. When I try to run `vagrant up` on my personal Ubuntu image, with a separate Vagrantfile, I get the following error:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

AWS Provider:
* An access key ID must be specified via "access_key_id"
* A secret access key is required via "secret_access_key"
* An AMI must be configured via "ami" (region: #{region})
```

I'm not trying to connect to AWS. I'm just trying to set up my first personal image on my laptop.

Comment: Can you provide the part of `provider` in your Vagrantfile?

Comment: everything in the `Vagrantfile` is stock, created upon `vagrant init`. The only part of the file not commented out is `config.vm.box ="puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64"`

Comment: can you run vagrant with `--provider` option?

Comment: that works. `vagrant up --provider virtualbox`. thanks!

Comment: you may have default env variables that refers to the provider, you can check by running `env | grep VAGRANT` you can then disable the default AWS provider by changing the value or removing the variables

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you actually have VirtualBox installed. I witnessed this error message today and it was because I had the `vagrant-aws` plugin installed but not VirtualBox. Installing VirtualBox was all that was needed to fix the problem.
2. If for some reason that still fails, then, per [the OP's comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431011/vagrant-keeps-trying-to-use-use-aws-plugin-how-to-stop#comment52727402_32431011), try using `vagrant up`'s `--provider` option:

   ```
   vagrant up --provider virtualbox
   ```

Answer (score 1):

By default Vagrant will go through all of the `config.vm.provider` and will choose the first usage provider, so you should add `virtualbox` before `aws`:

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
    v.memory = 4096
    v.cpus = 2
  end
```

or choose different provider manually either by `--provider` as already mentioned, or `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` variable:

```
VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=virtualbox vagrant up
```

or use `config.vm.provider` with no configuration in order to set the order in your Vagrantfile like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ... other config up here

  # Prefer VirtualBox Fusion before VirtualBox
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox"
  config.vm.provider "aws"
end
```

See: [Basic provider usage](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/basic_usage.html) at vagrantup.com

---

If you need to use AWS provider, these error means you need to set-up the right credentials by using `aws configure` command, so `~/.aws/credentials` can be created with your `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` values. For [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) configuration, check [README](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) file of the plugin (basically you need to add `aws.ami` into your Vagrant file).